# Text ellipses to fit rectangle in svg using d3 and React

Tags: reactjs, svg, d3.js

I'm trying to make sure that the text will fit my rectangle. I have tried to use `getComputedTextLength()` and `foreignObject` solutions, but I don't know how to use them in my context and failed miserably. For now I am just changing my text to the shorter version whenever the rectangle is shorter than some threshold, but that doesn't work well for obvious reasons. Can you help? Here is my code:

```
export const SingleKeyRow = ({isPrimary, data, innerWidth, rowHeight, buttonDisplacement, xScale, colorScale}) => {
    const textYPosition = (rowHeight/2)+5.5;
    const textXPosition = d => (xScale(d.endDate)+xScale(d.startDate))/2;

    const ticks = xScale.ticks();
    const tresholdWidth = 4* (innerWidth / (ticks.length - 1));
    const shortLabel = d => d.allocation;
    const longLabel = d => `${d.allocation} (${d.balance} FTE)`;
    const rectWidth = d => xScale(d.endDate) - xScale(d.startDate);
    const rectColor = d => isPrimary ? colorScale(d.balance) : "white";
    return (
        <svg width={innerWidth} height={rowHeight}>
            <g key={data.key} transform={`translate(${buttonDisplacement},0)`}>
                {data.map((d, idx) => (
                    d.allocation &&
                    <Fragment key={idx}>
                        <rect x={xScale(d.startDate)}
                            height={rowHeight}
                            width={rectWidth(d)}
                            fill={rectColor(d)}
                            stroke={"black"}
                            strokeWidth={0.5}
                        >
                            <title>{longLabel(d)}</title>
                        </rect>
                        {rectWidth(d) > tresholdWidth &&
                            <text x={textXPosition(d)} y={textYPosition}
                                textAnchor={"middle"}>{longLabel(d)}
                            </text>
                        }
                        {rectWidth(d) <= tresholdWidth) &&
                            <text x={textXPosition(d)} y={textYPosition}
                                 textAnchor={"middle"}>{shortLabel(d)}
                            </text>
                        }
                   </Fragment>
               ))}
            </g>
        </svg>
)
}
```